# Matlab - plotting points on the complex plain with certain color

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, visualization, complex-numbers

I have a uint8 matrix

```
A = (1:512,1:512,1:3)
```

which contains information about an 512x512 RGB image. I Also have a matrix B which is in the format of

```
B = (1:512,1:512)
```

which holds complex numbers. Now I would like to plot every complex number

```
B(x,y)
```

on the complex plane with RGB color of

```
A(x,y,1:3)
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What does plotting a complex number with a fixed RGB value look like? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: For example B(1,1) = 2+3i. This corresponds to the point (2,3) on the 2D complex plane. So I would like to plot the complex plane with a point at (2,3). The point should have the color r = A(1,1,1), g = A(1,1,2), b = A(1,1,3). 

The goal of the program is to have a color map where every pixel has a complex value. Then transform it with a mathematical function and plot the result. So its basically an image transformation.

Comment: What if there are repeated values in B? You’d paint the same output pixel with two different colors? I would understand it better if you intended to paint (in your example here) the pixel at (1,1) with `A(2,3,:)`, ie using `A` as a lookup table for the complex values.

Comment: We already were confronted with this case. In this situation we actually dont care about points getting repainted with a different color. I know that we are loosing information there in the output but for the most transformations we wont to use this is not critical.

Answer (score 2):

1) Make your color matrix of the size Mx3 (where M is the total number of your points):

```
A=reshape (A,512*512,3);
```

2) Use Scatter plot:

```
scatter(real(B(:)), imag(B(:)), [], A/255)
```

Note that here your colormap should be from 0 to 1. Assuming that your original A contained the values from 0 to 255, you need to divide by the maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for r=1:512
       for c=1:512
         plot( B(r,c) ,'Color',reshape(A(r,c,1:3),1,3),'LineStyle','none','Marker','o')
       end
    end
```

I couldnt figure out how to make the reshape work in vectorized form without an error. This works though (albeit very slowly)!